# Upgrade from 8GB to 16GB HP Laptop 250

Tags: laptop, memory

I have a Laptop with this specification:

```
HP Laptop 250 G2
Intel Pentium CPU N3510 @1.99GHz
8 GB RAM
500GB HDD
```

I want to know if I can upgrade the RAM to complete 16GB RAM (One Slot) as it completely slows my system down when running some Development environment like K2 smartforms , Android Studio and the rest.

Comment: Can't you find this information from the user guide that came with the laptop, or find it on the internet?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [Hp site](https://support.hp.com/lt-en/document/c04044564#AbT2), Memory section :

- Standard `DDR3L SDRAM` (1600 MHz)
- Two SODIMM slots supporting dual-channel memory
- **Standard memory up to 8192MB Maximum**
- **Upgradeable to 16384MB with optional 8192MB SODIMMs in slots 1 and 2**
- Dual-channel
- Maximized dual-channel performance requires SODIMMs of the same size
  and speed in both memory slots

> I want to know if i can upgrade the RAM to complete 16GB RAM (One Slot)

It seems that you can upgrade your laptop's RAM up to 16GB but only by using both motherboard's slots.

You cannot use one slot with a 16GB ram module as the maximum recognized memory size per slot is 8GB.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, Intel's official website says:

https://ark.intel.com/products/76751/Intel-Pentium-Processor-N3510-2M-Cache-2-00-GHz-

[image]

So the N3510 CPU only supports 8G memory at most, if we upgrade memory from 8G to 16G  , It is meaningless.